# Finding the order number of an element in a list

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to find the order number an item in list for example:

```
lst = [ a, b, [c,d], e, f]

order([c,d]) = 2
order('e') = 3
```

I think of this way :

```
def order(item,lst):
    if lst[0] == item:
       return n
    else:
       return order(item,lst[0:])
```

But it gives error (related recursion depth). What is my fault? Or how can i do it?

Comment: Take a look at [pythontutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=lst+%3D+%5B+'a',+'b',+%5B'c','d'%5D,+'e',+'f'%5D%0A%0A%0Adef+order(lst,+item)%3A%0A++++if+lst%5B0%5D+%3D%3D+item%3A%0A+++++++return+n%0A++++else%3A%0A+++++++return+order(lst%5B0%3A%5D,+item)%0A++++%0Aprint+order(lst,+%5B'c','d'%5D)%0Aprint+order(lst,+'e')&mode=display&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&py=2&curInstr=0) to see what your program is doing.

Comment: What is `n` in your example?

Comment: i have written it in the wrong way, should it be 0? I dont think that is the way. I just could not find

Comment: What should it be? Think about what you are trying to return from the function.

Comment: for example if it is the first element it should return 0.

Answer (score 6):

Why not just use `.index()`?

```
In [1]: l = [ a, b, [c,d], e, f]
In [2]: l.index([c,d])
Out[2]: 2
In [4]: l.index(e)
Out[4]: 3
```

If you really need a recursive function, use the following:

```
def order(item, l, n=0):
    if l:
        if l[0] == item:
            return n
        elif len(l) >= 2: # for python 2, use "else:"
            return order(item, l[1:], n+1)
```

And if recursion is not a must but you can't use `.index()`, use a for loop:

```
def order(item, l):
    for i,v in enumrate(l):
        if v == item:
            return i
```

With both methods, just call `order([c,d], lst)`

Comment: **-1** _"don't use `if not l:` since it will only check if `l is not False and l is not None and l is not 0`"_. [Wrong](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__). It also checks `len(l) != 0`.

Comment: @Eric Right, fixed. I guess we all learn something new everyday :P

Comment: Which makes your `if len(l) >= 2` redundant, since that condition is implied/enforced by the first `if`s

Comment: @Eric You're wrong on this one. Try what would happen to `order(3, [5])`. The first check for `l` would be `True` and an index error would raise on `return order(item, l[1:], n+1)`.

Comment: Wrong again. You can take a slice beyond the size of a list without an error: `[1, 2, 3][9001:] == []`

Comment: @Eric Nope: `>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a[4:]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    a[4:]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: 2vs3, perhaps? Works fine for me in python 2.7.3 (and is [documented](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.IndexError) behaviour)

Comment: @Eric Right, I've got `3.3.0`. Silly us ^^ **edit:** Python 3 documentation seems to say the same, maybe the problem is with my computer here... O.o

Comment: Now why the second downvote, I already fixed all the issues and even added a comment for `Python 2` ?

Comment: No, it should work fine [even in python 3](http://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#IndexError)

Answer (score 1):

1. Your function returns n in the base case, yet never assigns anything to it.  If the thing you are looking for is in the first element, it should return 0.
2. Your recursive case passes the whole list, which is why the recursive never ends.  If you passed lst[1:], then lists would get smaller with each call, but you'd need to add 1 to the result (in effect, everything is shifted down 1 place in each recursive call).

Comment: Passing `lst[1:]` will result in an empty list being passed on the last cycle, which will then error on `lst[0]`.

Comment: Original spec did not define what to do if item wasn't in list, I (perhaps incorrectly) assumed item was known it be in the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
def order(item, lst,n=0):
    if not lst:
        return None
    elif lst[0] == item:
        return n
    else:
        return order(item, lst[1:],n+1)

lst = ['a', 'b', ['c', 'd'], 'e', 'f']

order(['c', 'd'], lst)
```

*out:*

```
2
```

Answer (score -1):

Python has a builtin function to do this:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', ['c', 'd'], 'e', 'f']

assert lst.index(['c', 'd']) == 2
assert lst.index('e') == 3
```

If you want to fix your own function, you need a base case:

```
def order(item, lst):
    if not lst:
        return None
    elif lst[0] == item:
        return n  # You need to calculate n here. 
                  # I'm not doing your homework for you
    else:
        return order(item, lst[1:])
```

Comment: @EzgiAkçora: That's because you never even wrote that part. I just fixed your recursion problem. What's wrong with using `.index` here?

Comment: Eric, its probably a homework question and they are not "allowed" to use `.index()` (or they haven't been taught the method).